# Cassandra: best usage of partition and row key

Tags: cassandra

I have the following data structure:

```
{
   ClientId: string,
   ItemId: string,
   Item : string
}
```

I want to store this data in a Cassandra cluster. I know that some clients have much more items than others, yet I want to store data evenly on every node of my cluster since I have only one single query by ClientId and Item id together.

As far as I get I need to specify partition key like  to distribute data evenly, so in CQL it would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace.mytable
(
    ClientId text,
    ItemId text,
    Item text,
    PRIMARY KEY((ClientId, Id))
);
```

Do I need to specify anything as a row key? ClientId+ItemId uniquely identifies any row, so should I put anything after the first closing ")"?

Comment: Your item id is going to change each time right? Why do you want that as a part partition key. You shall put it in clustering key portion I feel.

Comment: It is not an e-commerce site. Item - is a big chunk of text, not related to buying. I want to partition by clientId and ItemId since Item might be a few megabytes text

Answer (score 0):

The one way is to make a hash of your partition keys and then use the hash as the partition key.

Also you could also add the time of the last purchase in there **((ClientId, ItemId, lastPurchaseTime))**

Comment: App is not about purchasing, but could you elaborate you answer please? If ClientId + ItemId is guaranteed unique pair, why would I want to add the time into my partition key? What would it allow me todo?

Comment: You wanted to make sure the data was distributed evenly, so you could add in the time of the purchase to the partition key to help partition better, usually this stuff only matters with the byte ordered partitioner. If you use the random partitioner you wont have to worry about this too much.

Comment: There's no need to hash anything for your primary key when using Murmur3/RandomPartitioner (which already hash the key).  A timestamp in the primary key also wouldn't be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to specify anything as a row key? ClientId+ItemId uniquely identifies any row, so should I put anything after the first closing ")"?

Your example schema will do exactly what you want and work well.  There's no need to add anything else to the primary key.

(If you added more columns to the primary key, they would serve as clustering columns, which control the ordering of the rows on disk for a single partition.)